# How to change Default Page Title Field in Kentico

Tags: kentico

In the Page Type area, the "Page name source field" is set to ProjectCode, which I want. However, my page titles seem to be set up as "'Page name source field' | Website Name", which I do not want.

Is there a way to change the page title structure for that page type so it pulls from a different field on the page type?

[image: Screenshot of page's fields]

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, this is managed in the **Settings** of the site rather than at a page level.

Navigate to **Settings > Content** in the *Settings* application. Then, under the **Metadata** section, you will find a setting called **Page title format**.

You can either *remove* `{%prefix%} -`, or set a more desirable value in the **Page title prefix** setting.

[image: Page title format setting]

In addition, you can change the value for the **Page title** in the *Metadata* tab for the document and make it use a macro, such as `{% CurrentDocument["ProjectID"] #%}`.  Also, looking at your notes, you *could* change your page type so that the Project ID is treated as the document title maybe?

Comment: Okay, this helps. I have "{%pagetitle_orelse_name%}" .. So I assume that "pagetitle" refers to in the page's individual metadata page, setting the title manually.  

"name" must refer to the "Page name source field" from my original post screenshot? If so, how can I make it so it grabs a different field first if its populated. The field name I want to use is "ProjectCode"  

This all assumes you can't set page title formats for individual page types?

Comment: That can be a little more tricky, as the settings apply to **all** document types.  What you can do is provide default values to the SEO fields (page title and description if you like) using macros.  To set this at the page type, you need to promote the field and add a default value to something like `{% CurrentDocument["ProjectID"] #%}`.  I'll update the answer with this so it makes more sense.

Comment: On reflection, the default value for some reason does not seem to be sticking.  I'll look into this a little further for you.

Comment: To answer two of your points: 1) No, you can't really set a different format for each page type. 2) Yes, the `pagetitle_orelse_name` will pick up from the `DocumentPageTitle` if set, otherwise it grabs the `DocumentName`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help and in advance for any more help you can provide. 

To be clear on what my objectives are..I wanted the Page Type display name in the left sidebar to be the "ProjectCode" field. But that also changes the page title to the "ProjectCode" field. Instead, I want the page title to stay the way it was, using the "Name" field. [screenshot of left sidebar](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/0Z3X1o263b3V1i2W391m/Image%202018-04-26%20at%207.55.20%20AM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Settings > Content has the Page Title format.

{%pagetitle_orelse_name%}  will pull the name of the document or the set page title on the metadata tab of the page.

Comment: Got it. That's what I have. But I want to use a page field as the title if possible. Can I do that? Is it not possible to set different Page Title structures for different page types?